# Entity Framework: WillCascadeOnDelete and Include

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I got a database model like this:

```
class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

My `modelBuilder` configurations looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(x => x.Username).IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Orders).WithRequired(x => x.User).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().ToTable("Orders", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Property(x => x.OrderName).IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Property(x => x.UserID).IsRequired();
}
```

The sql for table `dbo.Orders` looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders (
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    OrderName nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
    UserID int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Users FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES dbo.Users (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I can see in sql server profiler that when im executing:

```
dbContext.Users.Remove(dbContext.Users.Include(x => x.Orders).First(x => x.ID == 1));
```

EF is deleting all orders seperatly before it's deleting the user. I thought that EF rely on `ON DELETE CASCADE` specified in SQL server foreign key when setting `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` (which is the default behaviour for relationships in EF).

Why EF acts like this and how can I tell EF that it's not needed to remove the `Order`s before removing the `User`?

Comment: I think the issue is how list object are handled in c#.  List are handle by reference which may be why you are seeing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the dependent entities loaded in the change tracker, then EF will apply the cascading behavior in SaveChanges().

> The delete behavior configured in the EF Core model is only applied
>   when the principal entity is deleted using EF Core and the dependent
>   entities are loaded in memory (that is, for tracked dependents). A
>   corresponding cascade behavior needs to be setup in the database to
>   ensure data that is not being tracked by the context has the necessary
>   action applied. If you use EF Core to create the database, this
>   cascade behavior will be setup for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#delete-behaviors

If you don't want that, then don't fetch the orders.  Instead just new-up a stub user and delete it.

```
var stubUser = new User() {ID = 1};
dbContext.Users.Remove(stubUser);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This works. Isn't it possible to tell EF that it's not needed to delete dependent entities since SQL server does this?

Answer (score 0):

> You can remove these cascade delete conventions by using:

```
//Remove cascade delete conventions 
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

■ In the above example, EF appllies a set of conventions (convention applies to all your entities) when building the model, and you can override the conventions with the fluent configuration or attributes as shown below:

■   The following code configures the relationship to be required and then disables cascade delete (only for the related entity):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Department)
    .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**Update:** If you have `FK` related data that to be affected by this convemtion, then you could use Nullable FK as shown below. The above code snippet will create a nullable `DepartmentId` column in the database because we have used `Nullable<int>` type (`?` is a shortcut for `Nullable<int>`).

```
public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
```

Comment: If I set `WillCascadeOnDelete`, entity framework throws an exception: "The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.".

Comment: See my update please and let me know if it fix the problem.